# How to generate a realization from a transition matrix?

Tags: python, markov-process, transition-matrix

Consider a Markov chain of 4 states described by the transition matrix,
$$
T_{ij} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.40 & 0.56 & 0.03 & 0.01\\
0.45 & 0.51 & 0.04 & 0.00\\
0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.99
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can I generate a realisation of the Markov chain from it in python using the numpy arrays? What exactly it means by realisation of the Markov chain?

````py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ [ 0.40, 0.56, 0.03, 0.01],
               [0.45, 0.51, 0.04, 0.00],
               [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 ],
               [0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.99 ]])
```
````

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=simulate+markov+chain. Using that search I found my old post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115956/919 which contains complete code to simulate a Markov chain from a transition matrix.

Comment: A realisation of a Markov chain requires (a) a starting distribution and (b) a number of terms in the sequence. Given these inputs, the Markov property means generating one term after and conditional on another.