# Proposed transition matrix for MCMC in two-state Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

Suppose we would like to model the weather (either sunny $S$ or cloudy $C$) using a two-state Markov Chain, given a set of data collected from 10000 days:
$$CCCSSSSSSCCCSSSSSSCCCC...$$

We can use the metropolis-hastings algorithm to get a target transition matrix $P$ whose invariant distribution is given by
$$\pi = \left(\frac{\text{# of $S$'s from the data}}{10000}, \frac{\text{# of $C$'s from the data}}{10000}\right)$$
from the data.

Now how do we choose the proposed transition matrix $Q$? Naturally, we don't want to choose $Q$ to be $$Q = \begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
because then a typical sample from this $P$ would look like
$$CCSCSSCSCSCCSCSCCCSCCS...$$
(which is unrealistic for modeling the weather) instead of our data
$$CCCSSSSSSCCCSSSSSSCCCC...$$

Is there a systematic way of picking the $Q$ given the data set like above? I know the intuition would be say let
$$Q = \begin{pmatrix}
0.9 & 0.1 \\
0.1 & 0.9 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
but the $0.9$ and $0.1$ are still guesses.

Comment: You can't accomplish this with just two states.  Use more.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115883 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32531 for details.

Comment: @whuber In case we have say 3 states ( S, C, and Rain), given a set of data, would we be able to pick the proposal matrix $Q$ in some "optimal" way? Edit: just saw the link, I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: You don't pick the matrix: you estimate it from the observed frequencies.  The states you need correspond to *sequences* of `C` and `S`, not additional types of weather!  These sequences are called "n-grams" ($n$ is the length).

Comment: @whuber I guess we would have to use state space like $\{SSSS, SSSC, SSCC, ...\}$, right?

Comment: You could use a state space of $(n_s, n_c)$, where the indices refer to the number of consecutive observations in each state; obviously one of the two will always equal zero.   Then your transition matrix is of size at least equal to the sum of the two maximum sequence lengths.

Comment: @jbowman That's a nice idea.  In effect, it amounts to representing the sequence as a run-length encoding and modeling *those* transitions.  One might want to go a step further and study transitions of ordered pairs of such codes, thereby introducing some extra "memory" into the system. This would be needed if, say, long periods of drought were occasionally punctuated by rainy days. It would also provide a mechanism to limit the number of states: *e.g.,* a sequence 20 C's could be considered a sequence of 10C's followed by 10C's.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a major confusion behind the question: MCMC techniques are simulation tools that aim at reproducing generations from a known distribution, e.g., a posterior distribution in a Bayesian setting. They are not inference methods.

In the current setting, if the transition matrix $P$ is the quantity of interest and is inferred from the data at hand, an MCMC method such as Metropolis-Hastings would operate on the space of such transitions matrices, provided a prior distribution on the $P$'s and a sampling distribution on the data, indexed by $P$, are given .